# Import npm library with other files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-flags package for using flag in react native.

In react-native-flags, it uses flag images.
It works fine in online but not working in offline.

I think "import Flag from 'react-native-flags'" is not importing images files.

Is there anyway to resole this problem?
I want to use it in offline mode.

Thanks for your time.
Regards

Comment: online offline mean connecting to network? Checked the source from frostney/react-native-flags all the image stored locally

Comment: Well, when I am using this code "import Flag from 'react-native-flags" I think we import only js files not images. Is there any mistake in my thought?

Comment: It's strange that even the npm package including all the flags but it does not use the local flag... but there's an alternative way for important the flag by `import ADFlag from 'react-native-flags/flags/flat/16/AD.png';`
Let see is it work.

Comment: Ok but should I import all of the images like this?

Comment: Will try to figure out the reason by looking inside the source file when spare time, let see has anyone can fix it or hope can be replied you in few days...